# XY scatter plot with heatmap strip at margin in r

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2, lattice, r-grid

Here data and hypithesis:

```
set.seed(1234)
myd <- data.frame (X = rnorm (100), Y = rnorm (100, 10, 3))
```

just catorizing X and Y, sometime this may be different variable than X and Y
and is category itself

```
myd$xcat <- cut (myd$X, 10)
myd$ycat <- cut (myd$Y, 10)
```

I want to make nice plot like the following, where the catories are plotting as strip of heatmap plots
[image]

```
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(myd, aes(x=X, y=Y)) +    geom_point(shape=1)  + theme_bw()
```

Is this possible ggplot2 or other packages or need a specialized solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to make three separate plots with `ggplot2` and then use `viewport()` and `grid.layout()` to arrange them together.

First plot contains just middle part (scatter plot). `px` and `py` are heatmaps (made with `geom_tile()`) for the x and y axis. Most important part is to use the same `theme()` settings in plots (just change x to y). Used `color="white"` for some elements to ensure that there is a place for that element (to have correct dimensions) but they are not visible on plot.

```
#Scatter plot without axis titles
p<-ggplot(myd, aes(x=X, y=Y)) +    geom_point(shape=1)  + 
  theme_bw() + theme(axis.title=element_blank())

#tile plot for the x axis
px<-ggplot(myd,aes(x=xcat,y=1,fill=xcat))+geom_tile()+
  scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0,0))+
  scale_fill_hue(h=c(0,180))+
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0),breaks=1,labels="10")+
  theme(legend.position="none",
        axis.title=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_text(color="white"),
        axis.ticks.y=element_line(color="white"))

#tile plot for the y axis
py<-ggplot(myd,aes(x=1,y=ycat,fill=ycat))+geom_tile()+
  scale_y_discrete(expand=c(0,0))+
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0),breaks=1,labels="1")+
  scale_fill_hue(h=c(181,360))+
  theme(legend.position="none",
        axis.title=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_text(color="white"),
        axis.ticks.x=element_line(color="white"))

#Define layout for the plots (2 rows, 2 columns)
layt<-grid.layout(nrow=2,ncol=2,heights=c(7/8,1/8),widths=c(1/8,7/8),default.units=c('null','null'))
#View the layout of plots
grid.show.layout(layt)

#Draw plots one by one in their positions
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(layout=layt))
print(py,vp=viewport(layout.pos.row=1,layout.pos.col=1))
print(p,vp=viewport(layout.pos.row=1,layout.pos.col=2))
print(px,vp=viewport(layout.pos.row=2,layout.pos.col=2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A solution in `base` plot:

```
brX <- seq(min(myd$X),max(myd$X),length=11)
brY <- seq(min(myd$Y),max(myd$Y),length=11)

layout(matrix(c(1,0,2,3),nrow=2),width=c(2,8),height=c(8,2))
par(mar=c(0,3,5,0))
plot(NA,ylim=range(myd$Y),xlim=c(0,1),axes=F,ann=F,xaxs="i")
rect(0,brY[-length(brY)],1,brY[-1], 
     col=colorRampPalette(c("red","yellow","green"))(length(brY)-1))

par(mar=c(0,0,5,5))
plot(NA,xlim=range(myd$X),ylim=range(myd$Y),ann=F,xaxt="n",yaxt="n")
abline(h=pretty(myd$Y),v=pretty(myd$X), col="grey95")
points(myd$X,myd$Y,pch=21)
axis(3)
axis(4)

par(mar=c(3,0,0,5))
plot(NA,xlim=range(myd$X),ylim=c(0,1),axes=F,ann=F,yaxs="i")
rect(brX[-length(brX)],0,brX[-1],1, 
     col=colorRampPalette(c("blue","white","red"))(length(brX)-1))
```

[image]